# Objective-C: Calling a mutable array in an object

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an array in a class:

The SeqModel.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface SeqModel : NSObject {

    NSMutableArray *stepVolume;

}

-(void) initStepVolume;

-(void) setStepVolume:(char)stepnumber
           volume:(char)volume;

-(NSMutableArray *) stepVolume:(char)stepnumber;

 @end
```

and the SeqModel.m:

```
#import "SeqModel.h"

@implementation SeqModel

-(void) initStepVolume
    {for (char i=0;i<65;i++){
        [stepVolume addObject: [NSNumber numberWithChar:64]];
        }
    [stepVolume addObject:nil];}

-(void) setStepVolume:(char)stepnumber
               volume:(char)volume;
{[stepVolume replaceObjectAtIndex:stepnumber withObject:[NSNumber numberWithChar:volume]];}

-(NSMutableArray *) stepVolume:(char)stepnumber
    {return [stepVolume objectAtIndex: stepnumber];}

@end
```

In my NSView I create the object and initialize it with no errors or warnings:

```
@implementation BeatView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        seq1 = [[SeqModel alloc] init];
        [seq1 initStepVolume];

     }
    return self;
}
```

But a function later a call like that

```
char temp = [seq1 [stepVolume objectAtIndex: [NSNumber numberWithChar:4]]]
```

gives me an "Use of undeclared identifier 'stepVolume'" in the editor. Searched and searched and found no solution. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
char temp = [seq1 [stepVolume objectAtIndex: [NSNumber numberWithChar:4]]]
```

has at least 4 problems:

1. The `objectAtIndex` method takes a parameter of type `NSUInteger`, not `NSNumber`.
2. The `SeqModel` class does not provide public access to the `stepVolume` instance variable.
3. The use of square brackets is all wrong.
4. There is nothing defined in the `SeqModel` class that returns a `char`.

Try:

```
char temp = [[seq1.stepVolume objectAtIndex:4] charValue];
```

But this is a problem because `stepVolume` isn't public. You need to add a property. Better yet, add a method that takes and index and returns a char.

Comment: Thanks. But why is an array so different? I have a lot of other variables (ints, chars and strings) and they all work without being a property.

Answer (score 1):

For starters you're never actually initializing the `NSMutableArray` anywhere. So in this, you should probably do that.

```
- (void)initStepVolume
{
    // Create array
    stepVolume = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (char i = 0; i < 65; i++){
        [stepVolume addObject:[NSNumber numberWithChar:64]];
    }
}
```

And then I don't think you want to return an array but rather the number inside like so

```
-(NSNumber *)stepVolume:(char)stepnumber
{
    return [stepVolume objectAtIndex:stepnumber];
}
```

Finally you should change your last line to

```
char temp = [[seq1 stepVolume:4] charValue];
```

I don't know what the deal with all the `char`'s is but I'd suggest using ints or floats for volume and indexes.

Comment: Thanks! I have all the chars cause the numbers I have to store are less then 200...

Comment: I see. Good optimization then :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant:

```
char temp = [[seq1.stepVolume objectAtIndex:4] charValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing this:

```
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *stepVolume;
```